# On-reader applications for Impinj Revolution

Tags: c#, embedded

I'm trying to start developing RFID-reader apps. I've read that in the past you had to do it in C or C++, but nowadays there's a way to do it in .net (C# for ex.). I downloaded ETK, Documents and tools and latest SDK but I didn't find information about developing embedded apps in C# nor compiling .net solutions for arm processor (cause it's supposed to be executed by the reader).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Impinj Support Portal](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202755288-Speedway-Revolution-Embedded-Development-Tools-and-Sample-Application) they have GCC based tools for on reader application. They have detailed installation instructions.

The do support C# for the PC side as part of the [Octane SDK](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202755268-Octane-SDK)